# Setting up PHPUnit on OSX

Tags: installation, osx-snow-leopard, phpunit, pear

Though I'm sure others have eventually managed to figure this out, I've been following the various documentation out there and have been having a heck of a rough time of it.

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

Makes it sound pretty easy.  However depending on your setup, you might be going down a rabbit hole.

PEAR for example must be of a version higher than 1.8.1.  I had 1.8.0 at the time, so I went to find out how to update PEAR

```
PEAR upgrade-all
```

Gives an error.  No access.

```
sudo PEAR upgrade-all
```

Works, but upgrades the PEAR install owned by the user 'sudo' (and not your primary account... or something like that, short version is 5that it plain don't work)

```
cd ~
pico .bash_profile
```

add

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

give you the correct PEAR when you type PEAR, you're finally ready for step 1 of the install PHPUnit instructions.

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

Error.  You don't have access to /usr/local/temp

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/temp
```

Error. You don't have access to /usr/local/temp/channel.xml

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/temp/channel.xml
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
```

Error.

```
Registry directory is not writeable by the current user
```

BUT I'M ON A MAC!

```
/sigh
/facepalm
/tears
```

I've actually got a "working copy" of phpunit on my machine.  (YAY!) the odd problem is that 
 it only works when I type phpunit from one specific folder

```
cd /usr/local/PEAR
phpunit
```

^^ WORKS

```
cd ~
phpunit
```

^^ Returns

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 46

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Util/Filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 46
```

So close yet so far... I'm wondering if anyone has some input on getting this guy working right?

Comment: Most people should skip the accepted answer and [use Homebrew instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347339/114558).

Comment: homebrew does NOT work on mojave ... fyi (could not create symlink error)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ahhh.... OK ... I think I might have gotten it working now.

the answer was present in the PHPUnit documentation.
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/installation.html

```
After the installation you can find the PHPUnit source files inside your local PEAR directory; the path is usually /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit.
```

The Mac version of PEAR that I was running,  did install PHPUnit if I ran all the commands listed under the "SUDO" user
eg:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear upgrade-all
```

At this point, all the files are downloaded to /usr/local/pear but the command

```
phpunit
```

is looking to include files from /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit  The solution?  To copy the PHPUnit folder from

```
cp /usr/lib/pear/PHPUnit /usr/lib/php
```

OR

make a symlink

```
cd /usr/lib/php
ln -s /usr/lib/pear/PHPUnit PHPUnit
```

I've seen a lot of people with similar problems, but this particular solution hadn't come up in any of the threads I've seen.  Hopefully of use to you :) 
-Alex

Comment: I would recommend setting the include_path in your php.ini file to have the additional directory over the symlink, it is a little more conventional - including on OSX. Works for me. This is also what is recommended in the PEAR docs.

Answer (score 180):

To install via terminal:

```
curl https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -L -o phpunit.phar

chmod +x phpunit.phar

mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. It's the cleanest way to get phpunit installed globally on a mac.

Comment: And on osx, you'll need to create the "local" and "bin" folders. You can do this with `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lcoal/bin`

Comment: @Jarrod Did you misprint `lcoal`? Should it be `local`? Thanks

Comment: @Protocole Hey, yes I did! Should be `local`

Comment: this should be the correct answer, one thing though, not sure if Im the only one but I had to add "-L" to the curl command to make it follow redirect, otherwise I would end up with a 302 html page 

`curl https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -o phpunit.phar -L`

Comment: How to specify version ?

Answer (score 32):

We can install it using Homebrew

```
$ brew install phpunit
```

Comment: More precisely `brew install homebrew/php/phpunit `

Comment: @PetrPeller's comment is less precise in 2021. `Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.`. But `brew install phpunit` works

Answer (score 16):

Via homebrew (only if you've installed php via homebrew as well):

```
brew tap josegonzalez/php
brew install phpunit
```

Comment: Now, you don't need to tap the repository. `brew install phpunit` is enough.

Answer (score 5):

You can try installation with Composer. In this way you would isolate the PHPUnit version for the current project avoiding possible problems that might arise when using a single system-wide setup for different projects. As the PHPUnit documentation states (http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer), installation is quite easy.

Add the dependency to your composer.json file:

```
  {
     "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.0.*"
      }
  }
```

Then update dependencies:

```
composer update
```

And PHPUnit is ready to use by running :

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Remember to adjust this path if you change the composer install path, which defaults to 'vendor'.

Comment: The option --dev is not needed anymore though, as dev packages are installed by default now.

Answer (score 3):

Install PHPUnit

```
curl https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar -o phpunit.phar

chmod +x phpunit.phar

mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

OR if you have already install PHPUnit then just try this line to update PHPUnit by terminal

```
 phpunit --self-update
```

this will update your `phpunit.phar` file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download phpunit manually from: https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
2. Move to downloaded folder: `$ cd /to/the/download/directory`
3. Rename downloaded phpunit to the **phpunit.phar**
4. `$ chmod +x phpunit.phar`
5. `$ sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit`