# PHPUnit errors on Mac OSX 10.8

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to learn a little bit about PHPUnit Testing and I have PHPUnit installed via PEAR, but I am having NO luck with trying to get it running.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
    require_once "PHPUnit.php";
    class myclass_test extends PHPUnit_TestCase {
        protected $my;

        function setUp() {
            $this->$my = new Myclass('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
        }

        function teardown() {
            unset($this->my);
        }

        function testResponseCodeSuccess() {
            self::assertTrue($this->my->_validResponseCode(200));
        }
    }
```

I am running this on the console: `php myclass_test.php`

I am getting these errors:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/dennismonsewicz/Projects/PHP/test-php/tests/myclass_test.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit.php' (include_path='.:/Users/dennismonsewicz/pear/share/pear:/usr/local/share/pear:/usr/bin/pear') in /Users/dennismonsewicz/Projects/PHP/test-php/tests/myclass_test.php on line 2
```

I followed this tutorial: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.phpunit.intro.php

Anyone else run into these issues?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301300/setting-up-phpunit-on-osx

Comment: Thanks! It wound up being 1) I was extending the wrong class and 2) my `include_path` in my php.ini was set wrong

Comment: Then please add your solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309411/running-phpunit-on-command-line-errors-out/14325724#14325724