# Running PHPUnit on command line errors out

Tags: php, phpunit

I run this on the command line: `phpunit --version`

I get the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/lib/php/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 45
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Users/dennismonsewicz/pear/share/pear:/usr/local/share/pear:/usr/lib/php/pear/PHPUnit') in /usr/lib/php/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 45
```

Anyone else run into these issues? It is also causing me issues when I try to run my tests via the command line.

Comment: Botched installation, or incorrectly configured include_path. See PEAR documentation for more information: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

Comment: It was my include_path.. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ended being an issue with my include_path

This is my updated include path

```
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/usr/lib/php/pear"
```