# Running PHP Unit from Terminal - just not working

Tags: php, unit-testing, terminal, phpunit

I have installed PHP Unit and done everything the instructions tell me.

I'm told that I can just run:

```
$ phpunit
```

...and it will work. I may need to specify the config file and I can do that.

I have changed the directory to the PHP Unit folder, but nothing.

I am using Mac's Terminal if this means anything.

I have tried (with the error shown):

```
$ phpunit        -        $: command not found
phpunit          -        phpunit: command not found
php phpunit      -        ...doesn't return an error, but doesn't do return anything
% phpunit        -        fg: %: no such job
```

Also, the folder structure is like this:

```
- phpunit
    - php-code-coverage
    - php-file-iterator
    - php-text-template
    - php-timer
    - php-token-stream
    - phpunit
    - phpunit-mock-objects
        phpunit.php
        - PHPUnit (folder)
            - various things inside
```

... what am I actually running? The outer folder, inner folder or the phpunit.php file?

I must be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question: How'd you install PHPUnit? By "hand" (download it and just unzip it), via PEAR, ...?

Try executing (inside the phpunit folder):

```
./phpunit
```

Make sure the path where the phpunit executable lies is added to your `$PATH` variable.

A similiar question on SO on how to install phpunit can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301300/setting-up-phpunit-on-osx), general installation instructions [here](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html).